# How do you check if a Meteor.Collection is synchronized?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my application, I have an object whose fields are Meteor.Collections, some of which are not yet saved on the server. For example:

```
var tables = {};
tables["existent"] = new Meteor.Collection("existent"); // existent on server
tables["nonexistent"] = new Meteor.Collection(null); // nonexistent on server
```

I need to check if the collection also exists on the server. Is there any other way to check for that, other than attaching some flag to each Collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Collections have a field, `_name`, where the name passed to the constructor is stored. Therefore, if you check `collection._name`, it should return the name passed to it (if it was initialized with one), and `null` otherwise.